# The return type 'dynamic' isn't a 'bool', as required by the closure's context

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dynamic

I am implementing search bar in my flutter app. But the line `_allUsers.where((user) => user["name"].toLowerCase().contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase())).toList();` throws an error: *'The return type 'dynamic' isn't a 'bool', as required by the closure's context.'*
There is code:

```
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _allUsers = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Andy", "type": "student"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Aragon", "type": "student"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Bob", "type": "student"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "Barbara", "type": "teacher"},
    {"id": 5, "name": "Candy", "type": 'student'},
  ];
  void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> results = [];
    if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
      results = _allUsers;
    } else {
      results = _allUsers.where((user) => user["name"].toLowerCase().contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase())).toList();
    }
  }
```

When I try run this code in dartpad.dev it works, but in Android Studio it doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure you got error on same line? Its working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add a cast when you get the value from the map. Right now, the type is `dynamic` (because the map has been declared in such a way) which means type safety is thrown away:

```
  void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> results = [];
    if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
      results = _allUsers;
    } else {
      results = _allUsers
          .where((user) => (user["name"] as String)
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
    }
  }
```